# Failure of Hasse Principle for $x^2 - 5y^2=uv$ and $x^2-5z^2=(u+v)(u+2v)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, number-systems

Can we show the failure of [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) (or "local-global" principle) for these simultaneous quadratic equations?

\begin{eqnarray}
x^2 - 5y^2 &=& uv  \tag{1}\\
x^2 - 5z^2 &=& (u+v)(u+2v) \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
These are homogeneous polynomials so the left side variables are $[x:y:z] \in \mathbb{P}^2$ while the right side variables are $[u:v] \in \mathbb{P}^1$.

Two quadratics in 5 variables; this is a [del Pezzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Pezzo_surface) surface of degree $4$.

- two-dimensional Fano variety; non-singular [projective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_variety) algebraic surface with ample anti-canonical [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)) class (Here I just looked up the word "divisor" from algebraic geometry to see what it means here).
- intersection of two conics (in this case) $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^4$.

"Failure" here means that $X(\mathbb{Q})= \varnothing$ is empty even though $X(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ has points for all primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.  The lack of solutions is parametrized by the [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group).  In fact,$$\text{Br}(X)/\text{Br}(\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$
So we can ask for *adelic* solutions that don't [converge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to rational solutions.

---

The Brauer group of a *field* would be defined by the exact sequence:

$$ 0 \to \text{Br}(K) \to \bigoplus_{v \in S} \text{Br}(K_v) \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0 $$

The group splits by some sort of prime factorization and it's value is a rational number.  This is related to [Class Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory).  It's also called a "Galois cohomology" like this:
$$ \text{Br}(K) \simeq H^2(K, \mathbf{G}_m) $$
where $\mathbf{G}_m$ is the "multiplicative group", $\times$.

Comment: not clear what you already know here. Do you have a proof or reference for no solutions with at least one variable non-zero?  How about solutions for all p-adcs?

Comment: There will be solutions when the equation takes this form. $$x^2+5z^2=(u+v)(u+2v)$$